# How to get INTERESTS in the "facebook-nodejs-business-sdk"

Tags: node.js, npm, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-nodejs-business-sdk

I am developing an application to consume the facebook api using the package "facebook-nodejs-business-sdk" in version v9.0.

I'm looking for a method to get interests, but I can't find it.

I looked in the examples available in the package, but I can't find anything that allows me to search the search node.

Using the graph api explorer I can see that the code to make these calls with javascript is as follows:

```
FB.api( '/search','GET', {"type":"adinterest","q":"Golf","limit":"10000","locale":"pt_BR"}, function(response) { // Insert your code here } );
```

But the application is using the mentioned package and generally has specific methods for calls.

I'm a beginner in programming so I'm lost.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any reference to this in the SDK but seems you could call the [targeting search api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/targeting-search) by yourself with the following example:

```
const bizSdk = require('facebook-nodejs-business-sdk');

const access_token = '<the_token>';

const api = bizSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token);
const showDebugingInfo = true; // Setting this to true shows more debugging info.
if (showDebugingInfo) {
  api.setDebug(true);
}

const params = {
  'type' : 'adinterest',
  'q' : 'Golf',
  'limit' : '10000',
  'locale' : 'pt_BR',
};

api.call('GET',['search'], params).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(error => {
  console.log("something bad happened somewhere", error);
});
```

This code will output something like:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: '6003631859287',
      name: 'Golf',
      audience_size: 218921,
      path: [Array],
      description: null,
      disambiguation_category: 'Negócio local',
      topic: 'News and entertainment'
    },
    {
      id: '6003510075864',
      name: 'Golfe',
      audience_size: 310545288,
      path: [Array],
      description: '',
      topic: 'Sports and outdoors'
      ....
```

Hope this help

Comment: Oh thank you!! I didn't know this method api.call, it will be very usefull!!! Thank you very much!!!